# How to add specified filters in Java Streams Collectors Grouping

Tags: java, arrays, collections, java-stream

I can group Designation, Gender Is there a way I can then use the filter here like Gender 'Male' only

My code is

```
List<Employee> employeesList = new ArrayList<>();

employeesList.add(new Employee(101, "Glady", "Manager", "Male", 25_00_000));
employeesList.add(new Employee(102, "Vlad", "Software Engineer", "Female", 15_00_000));
employeesList.add(new Employee(103, "Shine", "Lead Engineer", "Female", 20_00_000));
employeesList.add(new Employee(104, "Nike", "Manager", "Female", 25_00_000));
employeesList.add(new Employee(105, "Slagan", "Software Engineer", "Male", 15_00_000));
employeesList.add(new Employee(106, "Murekan", "Software Engineer", "Male", 15_00_000));
employeesList.add(new Employee(107, "Gagy", "Software Engineer", "Male", 15_00_000));



Map<String, Map<String, Long>> multipleFieldsMap = employeesList.stream()
        .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDesignation, 
                        Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getGender, 
                                Collectors.counting())));
```

Comment: Filter first after the .stream()

Comment: why not [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) before trying to collect i.e before `grouping`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
employeesList.stream()
             .filter(employee -> employee.getGender().equals("Male"))
             .collect( ... );
```

You can use Stream’s [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-).